# How to launch chrome browser fullscreen in windows with new window and in specific monitor

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fullscreen, monitor, kiosk-mode

I've tried a lot of variations on windows shortcuts for Chrome to launch fullscreen kiosk mode in a specific monitor for desktops with none of them working with all the options at once.
Variations attempted:
"local path\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --window-position=0,0 -kiosk -new-window url
"local path\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen -new-window --window-position=0,0 url
chrome -kiosk -new-window --window-position=0,0 --app=url
chrome --start-fullscreen -new-window --windowposition=0,0 --app=url

just to help out any new users trying to replicate replace "local path" in the above with the directory path that gets you to the google chrome.exe application in your system. Also replace "url" with the full link to the page you want to load in chrome at launch. Right now all of the attempts have either kiosk fullscreen or location but not all in one working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some other help found a solution that works for me on all aspects in windows 10.

"local path\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="url" --window-position=1024,0 --kiosk --user-data-dir=c:/monitor2

Just use the maximum display area of your monitor to set window position. In this case Im launching on second monitor and primary is 1024 resolution.